# Programmatically Blurring combobox control in EXTJS 3.2.1 does not fire 'blur' event

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to implement a Confirmation Dialog box when the user closes a tab w/o saving.

To do this, I am using the component's (textfield, checkbox, combobox, etc.) 'change' event. However, since the 'change' event requires the field to blur, there is an issue if they the user changes a field but does not lose focus of the field BEFORE closing the tab.

To remedy this, I use the tab's 'beforeclose' event to programmatically blur() the active element, and hence fire the 'change' event if the field has changed:

```
listeners: {
    beforeclose: function(form) {
        var focusedEl = Ext.getCmp(document.activeElement.id);
        focusedEl.blur();

        if(tabRC.F('AgentCaseForm').dirty.items.length > 0) {                                                   
            return(confirm('There are unsaved changes on this tab. Are you sure you want to close?'));
        }
    }
}
```

This approach works for all controls (textfield, textarea, checkbox, datefield) EXCEPT for the combobox. The field blurs, but the 'blur' event does not fire and therefore the 'change' event does not fire. Is there a reason for this that I am missing? Thank you very much!

EDIT: I have tried programmatically firing the 'blur' event, but the 'change' event still does not fire.

```
focusedEl.fireEvent('blur');
```

EDIT 2: The solution was to do this:

```
var focusedEl = Ext.getCmp(document.activeElement.id);
if (focusedEl && focusedEl.isDirty()) {
    focusedEl.fireEvent('change');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Ext.form.ComboBox` is extending `Ext.form.TriggerField`, you can trigger blur programatically by

```
focusedEl.triggerBlur();
```